# Catalina : Bootcamp assistant stuck on Partitioning Disk

Tags: bootcamp, windows, catalina

I am trying to dual boot windows 10. Everything goes fine until It tries to partition disks.

This is my diskutil list response :

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB  disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB  disk0s1
   2:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB  disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB  disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume Untitled - Data         99.5 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.1 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.5 MB  disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB    disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Untitled                10.7 GB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume wnd                     757.8 KB  disk1s6

/dev/disk2 (external, physical): 
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB   disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS WinInstall              15.5 GB   disk2s1
```

Disk Utility Screens :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I had dual boot before, when I had mojave installed.  Then I removed it using boot camp assistant. Probably something went wrong.